# __transaction_atomic without transactional memory support enabled

Tags: c++, gcc, locking, atomic, transactional-memory

I was just compiling C/C++ code using `__transaction_atomic` but compiler error occurred

- `[Error] __transaction_atomic' without transactional memory support enabled`

Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    __transaction_atomic
    {
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How to figure it out? My compiler is GCC 4.9

Comment: You probably need `-fgnu-tm`

Answer (score 7):

You should compile code with transaction memory support enabled.
[From here](http://pmarlier.free.fr/gcc-tm-tut.html)

> Compiling a TM program with GCC **To enable the support for TM, the
>   '-fgnu-tm' compiler directive has to be added to the compilation
>   command line.** Example: gcc -Wall -fgnu-tm -O3 -o ll ll.c Note that
>   with the optimization level 0 (-O0), some of the TM optimization are
>   disabled (RaR, RaW, RfW, WaR, WaW, optimized stack memory barriers).